# JavaScript: Waiting for finish for specific time

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I'm new in javascript and I have a problem with busy waiting for function to finish. I don't have the code here, but I'll shortly explain that:

I have one function that can be executed 100 ms or even 10 s, let's call it **Foo1**

Then I have another function **Foo2**, which at first works with input parameters and then calls Foo1. One of input parameters is **time in milliseconds**, that I wanted to wait for function to end . In case that execution **exceeds this limit**, just do **finish** procedure and return. In case that Foo1 is finished **before the time** exceeds, return **earlier**.

My solutions are here in basic code syntax, but hopefully understandable.

## 1

```
// First wait for the specified time and then execute Foo1 - obviously one after another
self.Foo2 (time) {
    setTimeout(self.Foo1(),0);
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < now + time){ /* do nothing */ }     
}
```

## 2

```
/*This one, if I understand it well, creates a queue where at first DoWait
is executed, then Foo1 and after that all other DoWait - so practically 
we wait the whole time of execution.*/

var finished = false;
self.DoWait(time, now) {
    if(!finished && (new Date().getTime() < now + time)) {
        setTimeout(self.DoWait(time, now), 20); 
    } else {
        /* finish procedure */
    }
}

self.Foo2 (time) {
    setTimeout(function() { self.Foo1(); finished=true;},0);
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    self.DoWait(time, now)    
}
```

Do you know about some solution how it's possible to do it? I read about **workers**, but for creating worker you need the function in whole new file, but I would prefer something that can be done within the function / the file.
Thanks in advance for all answers.

Comment: The solution is not to do busy-waiting in JavaScript.

Comment: `setTimeout(self.Foo1(), 0)` calls `self.Foo1()` immediately, not after a timeout. You need to write `setTimeout(Foo1.bind(self), 0)`.

Comment: Actually `setTimeout(self.Foo1.bind(self), 0)`.

Comment: Thats true that it's executed immidiately, but you don't wait for result with zero timeout. And right know I want to wait for maximum time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `Promises` with a `race` will do what you're after.

[The MDN Docs cover it nicely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race), but I'll duplicate the code here:

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, 500, "one"); 
});
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, "two"); 
});

Promise.race([p1, p2]).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // "two"
  // Both resolve, but p2 is faster
});

var p3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, "three");
});
var p4 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(reject, 500, "four"); 
});

Promise.race([p3, p4]).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // "three"
  // p3 is faster, so it resolves               
}, function(reason) {
  // Not called
});

var p5 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, 500, "five"); 
});
var p6 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(reject, 100, "six");
});

Promise.race([p5, p6]).then(function(value) {
  // Not called              
}, function(reason) {
  console.log(reason); // "six"
  // p6 is faster, so it rejects
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. I want these two functions to work somehow in parallel. This Promise.race just executes these functions sequential and if some of them is finished it returns. But I want to run both of them somehow "parallel" and if some of them is finished then finish the whole function.

Answer (score 0):

You can call final procedure after a timeout inside Foo2. You can pass this timeout handle to Foo1. If Foo1 is done earlier, it can clear timeout created by Foo2 and call final procedure itself.

```
self.Foo2 (time) {
    /* Foo2 stuff */
    //call final procedure after set time
    var timeout = setTimeout(self.finalProcedure, time);
    //pass timout handle to Foo1
    self.Foo1(time, timeout);   
}

self.Foo1 (time, timeout) {
    var before = new Date().getTime();
    /* Foo1 stuff */
    var after = new Date().getTime();
    if((after - before) < time){ //finished earlier
        //clear timeout as Foo1 is done
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        //call final procedure
        self.finalProcedure();
    }
}

self.finalProcedure(){
    /* final steps */
}
```

Comment: Yes, but in case that Foo1 execution time > time, then timeout will be executed after Foo1 is finished, not after specified time.

Comment: Not really. timeout will get executed after whatever time Foo2 sets it to execute after, unless Foo1 clears it. It doesn't know about Foo1 or waiting for it.

Comment: I implemented it that way and it happened as I supposed. It will move the `setTimeout(self.finalProcedure, time)` to the end and executes `self.Foo1(...)`. If Foo1 execution time is too long, it waits until it's finished and clears the timeout. It's not multithreaded, so I guess it's not just interrupt Foo1 (if its just one line of code) and work with this timeout.